# Is there a specific DNN Table which can be used to store Product Reviews or third party data?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

I want to know if there is a specific DNN table in which I can store Product Reviews or any additional information?

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think at the moment you can only use ModuleSettings and TabSettings to achieve this?

Comment: I would put together your own table for that. I don't think you'll find anything built into DNN that could be used this way.

Comment: You can use an external provider like https://www.reviewbuddy.com/. It also can boost your google rankings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the SQLDataProvider from DNN to create a new Database table on the DNN database. I could've used our ERP database but this would've taken longer as I have to consult with other backend developers.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'{databaseOwner}[{objectQualifier}ProductReviews]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE {databaseOwner}[{objectQualifier}ProductReviews](
        ReviewID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,     
        SKU varchar(255),
        ReviewText varchar(255),
        DatePosted DATETIME,        
        RatingValue int,
        Author varchar(255),
        Show int
) 
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, an ecommerce module would have such a feature.  Do you have an ecommerce module?  (I think that you'd want to tie product reviews to products, so you'll need a place for products, too.

One product, Cart Viper includes reviews, comments, and ratings.

(I just happen to have been working on a site recently that uses Cart Viper, which is the only reason I mention it.)

Comment: We had a 3rd party shopping module but this kept us back as we have developed our own ERP system using VB.net and C#. We then decided to develop our own shopping modules.

Answer (score 1):

ModuleSettings and TabSettings are for storing specific settings to a module or a page (aka Tab), e.g. the used skin (theme), container layout, title etc. They should not be used for something else, as they always require a valid ModuleID or TabID, and if that module or page is deleted the entries are gone...

DNN is a very extensible system. If you need this functionality you may search for a module that provides it (e.g. in the DNN Store https://store.dnnsoftware.com, a basic form module could do) - or write one yourself if you are a bit into C# or VB.Net programming. Have a look at various tutorials you can find in the web, also videos on YouTube etc. - and last but not least the DNN Community Wiki (https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki), the Documentation (https://www.dnnsoftware.com/docs/index.html), the Community Blog (https://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog) and Documentation Center for Developers (https://www.dnnsoftware.com/docs/developers/index.html).

The Forum on the DNN site is also a good place to ask questions if you are stuck at some point, and also the DNN Connect group on Facebook.

Therefore:
Happy DNNing!
Michael